# Timeout error when creating ServiceBusMessageBatch in Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-sdk-.net

I have the following code where I start getting an error during long-running tests on the same Service Bus Client.

```
ServiceBusMessageBatch batch = this._serviceBusSender.CreateMessageBatchAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

The error is,

```
Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusException: 'The operation did not complete within the allocated time 00:01:00 for object request42. (ServiceTimeout)'
```

Why is this statement throwing this error? Is the creation of a batch object such a heavy operation that it can even timeout? If this is the case, should I switch to the overload of using the List of ServiceBusMessage instead of this batch mode?

My understanding is that this way of batch creation can protect me from creating a batch that the queue may not allow. I am finding it difficult to understand why it times out after 1 min

[image: Batch Creation Error] .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for a batch to be able to enforce limits on the size, it has to establish an AMQP link to the entity that you'll be sending to and read the maximum allowable message size from the service.  This results in a network operation that, in this case, timed out.  This overhead is performed only in the case that there is not an existing AMQP link already established - typically on the first call that requires a network operation.

What jumps out at me from your code is the use of `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` to perform sync-over-async.  This is really not a good idea and is very likely to cause contention in the thread pool that prevents continuations from being scheduled in a timely manner.  Because network operations in Service Bus are asynchronous - including establishing the AMQP link - delays in scheduling continuations would certainly increase the chance of timeouts.

I'd strongly advise refactoring your sync-over-async code paths and shifting to an asynchronous approach.  In those scenarios where it's not possible to go full async, limiting sync-over-async to the outermost layer of your code would be the next best thing.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I was aware of the forced sync using the GetAwaiter which I will refactor as you said. This was only for testing as the code is inserted inside a legacy code. For time being, I will see if the List of ServiceBusMessage can avoid this network connection establishment.

Comment: I fear that is just kicking the can down the road; if you're not paying to establish the link when creating a batch, you'll be doing so when sending (plus the network operation to send).    Something is causing either the network to run slowly or continuations to be delayed.